# ScrollViewer makes TextBox widen when typing longer texts, even though HorizontalScrollMode is disabled

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Grid inside a ScrollViewer (only vertical scrolling is enabled). I have a TextBox in that Grid, which ColumnSpan is 2, and its HorizontalAlignment is Stretch. Because of the ScrollViewer, if the user starts typing something really long, the TextBox will grow wider and wider, which I would like to avoid, it should be only as wide as the two columns it's spanning across, not widening them too.

I'm not sure how good of a practice would be to set it's MaxWidth to a constant, so I'd like to bind it instead to the two columns's ActualWidths.

In the column definitions:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*" x:Name="grdCol1"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*" x:Name="grdCol2"/>
```

The TextBox:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=grdCol1, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

The question is, how could I bind it to grdCol1 + grdCol2's ActualWidth? Or should I even go down this road? Is there a preferred, maybe cleaner way to do so?

Comment: I see, you are right they are different. But now your title is a bit misleading. Please consider updating it.

Comment: Sure, updated the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ScrollViewer was at fault here.

NOT WORKING:

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
```

WORKING:

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
```

You have to set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, as Hidden is not enough for this purpose.